# Jquery hide div/image until page loads using display:none

Tags: jquery, html, show-hide

I am trying to hide an image/div using display:none until the page loads, then it will slide in from page left. How do I get the image to show once the page is loaded and not take up space on the page before so. See: http://jsanim.com/ for example (pretend like the left cloud is 'bunny'.) A new kid thanks you for your help!

```
function init(){
    var manager = new jsAnimManager();  
bunnyFly = document.getElementById("bunny");

manager.registerPosition("bunny");

bunnyFly.setPosition(-1320,100); 

var anim = manager.createAnimObject("bunny");

anim.add({property: Prop.position, to: new Pos(320,100),  
duration: 2000}); 
anim.add({property: Prop.positionCircle(false), loop:-1, to: new Pos(-300,150), duration: 3000});  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite simple, just register the `window` object's `onload` event handler:

```
function init() {...}
window.onload = init;
```

The `Window` object in the DOM has an `onload` member of type `Function` that will get invoked when the corresponding `Window` is finished loading.

If you're using `jQuery`, you can use the `document.ready` event:

```
$(document).ready(init);
```

**EDIT**: You can access the `window` object from anywhere in your JavaScript code - it is a global object. You can indeed do this in a linked file via a `<script>` tag:

Blah.js:

```
function init() {
  //your code here...
}
window.onload = init;
//or
$(document).ready(init);
```

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <head>
       ...
   <script src="Blah.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
       ...
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Jacob- Can you elaborate a bit or drop a link to more info on this? Does the window.onload go on my linked js file or on the main page? Sorry- please dumb it down a little for me :)

Comment: Thank you Jacob- it works for me using the $(document).ready option, however I think I need the script to be delayed a little longer because the animated object's position seems to be affected by the height of the page before it finishes loading. Sometimes it positions correctly when it enters the page, other times it's too high, too low, etc. I should ask this as a separate question as well, but while I have you here... :)

Comment: Before the slideLeft, use this `.delay(1000)` (1 second).  for example: `$("#object").delay(500).slideDown();`

Comment: CRAP. It didn't work- I wasn't using display:none;. I tried adding both the window.onload and .ready at the end of my script, didn't work. I tried with and without <body onload="init()"> and it too didn't work. I just want the div 'bunny' element to be hidden until everything is fully loaded, but I can't turn off the 'display:none' once the script runs. HALPS?

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your code in

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   //put your code here
   $("#divId").slideDown(); //just an example, use your code for slideLeft
});
```

Comment: Your code is incorrect, you're passing an object to `ready` as opposed to a `function`.

Comment: `$(document).ready(init);` is no different.  You don't have to have a function called init.  My code is perfectly fine.